# unittest python module cant find module

Tags: python, unit-testing

Trying to use unittest module in python, but when running from cmd it can't find my module. ```

```
import unittest
import calc

class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        result = calc.add(10, 5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 15)
```

The file name is test_calc.py
in cmd I try run `py -m unittest test_calc.py`

It says it cannot find the module. Any Ideas why?

I use windows 10

Comment: *"It says it cannot find the module."* Show us the full original output!

Comment: Where is `calc` relative to where you are running your tests?

Answer (score 0):

```
import unittest
import calc

class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        result = calc.add(10, 5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 15)
```

`unittest.main()`

#Add the above line to your program if you're running from command line